# Are parenthesis not allowed in a Data Validation string?

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I am setting a data validation of a field through VBA. Everything runs fine until the point of Adding the validation to the field, and only on some of the validation strings. It is the strings that seem to be causing a problem.

I have the following Data Validation code:

```
If Not NewTarget Is Nothing Then
    With NewTarget.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=mys
    End With

    NewTarget.Value = MyList(1)
End If
```

The value of mys that fails is:

```
"Select One,Trade - Transportation - Utilities(9),Information,Finance -   Insurance - Real Estate,Professional - Business Services,Educational - Health Services,Leisure - Entertainment - Hospitality,Other Services (Except Public Administration),Public Administration"
```

The one that works is:

```
"Select One,Natural Resources - Mining,Construction,Manufacturing"
```

Do I need to remove the parenthesis from the string in order for the validation string to be accepted?

I have seen that using formulas from VBA do seem to cause problems with parenthesis in strings.

Comment: You can use parenthesis in Data Validation. How are you setting `mys`?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it isn't the parenthesis that are causing problems, it is the length of the string.

Formulas in Excel have a 256 character limit and Excel throws an exception when you exceed that limit.

Comment: You can bypass that limit by placing your entries in a spreadsheet range, and using that range address for the drop down.

Comment: That is what I did. I was unfamiliar with re-referencing named ranges, which is what I needed for the dynamic drop-downs if I used the spreadsheet.

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted.  [Debra Dagleish Contexture's website](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) has a lot of information on dynamic drop-down lists, and also dynamic dependent dropdowns, that you may find of use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `mys` is a range, do this:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=mys"
```